# For $b \gt 2$ , verify that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}=\frac{1}{b-2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

For $b \gt 2$ , verify that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}=\frac{1}{b-2}$$

This is how I tried..
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(b-2)}{(b-2)b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(b+n-1-2+1-n)}{(b-2)b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(b+n-1)-(1+n)}{(b-2)b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(b+n-1)}{(b-2)b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}-\frac{n!(1+n)}{(b-2)b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}=\frac{1}{b-2}\left(\frac{b-2}{b}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{b(b+1)...(b+n-2)}-\frac{(n+1)!}{b(b+1)....(b+n-1)}\right)$$

Now $$S_n=\frac{1}{b-2}\left[\frac{b-2}{b}+\left(\frac{2}{b}-\frac{3!}{b(b+1)}\right)+\left(\frac{3!}{b(b+1)}-\frac{4!}{b(b+1)(b+2)}\right)+...+\left(\frac{n!}{b(b+1)..(b+n-2)}-\frac{(n+1)!}{b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{b-2}\left[1-\frac{(n+1)!}{b(b+1)..(b+n-1)}\right]$$

All I need to show is that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{b(b+1)..(b+n-1)}=0$$ which I am unable to show.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821338).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{b(b+1)\cdot...\cdot(b+n-1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^{b}}{b(b+1)\cdot...\cdot(b+n-1)(b+n)}\cdot\frac{(n+1)(b+n)}{n^{b}}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^{b}}{b(b+1)\cdot...\cdot(b+n)}\cdot\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})}{n^{b-2}}=\Gamma(b)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})}{n^{b-2}}=0$$

where I have used that $b>2$ to justify the existence of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})}{n^{b-2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n! \over b\pars{b + 1}\ldots\pars{b + n - 1}}
     ={1 \over b-2}}$

> \begin{align}
> \mbox{Note that}\quad
> \Gamma\pars{b}&={\Gamma\pars{b + 1} \over b}
> ={\Gamma\pars{b + 2} \over b\pars{b + 1}}
> ={\Gamma\pars{b + 3} \over b\pars{b + 1}\pars{b + 2}}=\cdots
> \\[3mm]&={\Gamma\pars{b + n} \over b\pars{b + 1}\pars{b + 2}\ldots\pars{b + n - 1}}
> \end{align}
>   such that

\begin{align}&\color{#44f}{\large%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n! \over b\pars{b + 1}\ldots\pars{b + n - 1}}}
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{b} \over \Gamma\pars{b + n}}
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n\,{\Gamma\pars{n}\Gamma\pars{b} \over \Gamma\pars{b + n}}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n\,\int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{b - 1}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{1}\
\overbrace{\pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}nt^{n - 1}}}^{\ds{=\ \pars{1 - t}^{-2}}}
\ \pars{1 - t}^{b - 1}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{b - 3}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\left.-\,{\pars{1 - t}^{b - 2} \over b - 2}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
=\color{#44f}{\large{1 \over b - 2}}\,,\qquad\qquad b > 2
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$ and we used well known properties of it.

Answer (score 1):

$b = 3 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n!}}{{3 \times 4 \times ....\left( {n - 2} \right)}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {2n\left( {n - 1} \right)} \right)}  =  + \infty 
$

Comment: The products in the denominators in the first sum should go up to $n+2$, not $n-2$.